# How to update in nested schema in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am working on meteor. I am trying to make blog with commmenting system.For post insertion my schema is this:

```
Posts.insert({
                    post:post,
                    author:username,
                    date:date,
                    createdAt:new Date(),
                    comment:{
                        commentBy:'',
                        commentMsg:''
                    },
                    userId:Meteor.userId()
                })
```

At first the comment section will be blank. when user comment on particular post then comment section is filled.
I am trying to update this schema:

```
Posts.update(thisPost,{$addToSet:{comment.commentedBy:Name,comment.commentMsg:post}});
```

But its not working.How to do it right way??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for entering multiple comments the field should be an array.

```
comments:[{
   Commentedby:String,
   CommentedMsh:string
}]
```

You can either use $addtoset or $push,

```
db.update({_id:post._id},{$push:{comments:newComment}})
```

## OR

```
db.update({_id:post._id}, { $addToSet: { comments : comment });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put quotes around any dot references, like this:

```
Posts.update(thisPost,{$addToSet:{"comment.commentedBy":Name,"comment.commentMsg":post}});
```

The reason is because if you don't, your compiler will try and do object references locally, which is not what you want, if you pass it as a string, then Mongo will do it as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues that I could find in your provided information.
First is that the `comment` property should be an array/collection, so you should initiate it as following (renamed to comments):

```
Posts.insert({
    ...
    comments:[],
    ...
})
```

And second, and most important to answer you question, according to the documentation the first parameter on update should be either a selector, a ObjectID or a string id.
https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-update

So your update should look like this:

```
var comment = { commentBy: 'user-id', commentMsg: 'le-message' }
Posts.update(post._id, { $addToSet: { comments : comment });
```